# Consequences of a polytime algorithm for a decision problem reducible to 3SAT

Tags: np-complete, np, complexity-classes

If there is a polynomial time algorithm for a decision problem $A$, which is m-reducible to 3SAT, and 3SAT is NP-complete, does this prove that P=NP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem $A = \emptyset$ is polytime reducible to 3SAT (using a reduction running in constant time), and can be solved in polynomial time.

More generally, any problem in P is polytime reducible to 3SAT and can be solved in polynomial time.